# What is the purpose of Membership.ValidateUser()

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms-authentication, membership

I've been learning about the `MembershipProvider` class and I thought that the `Membership.ValidateUser()` method was supposed to be used to to log a user in.

However, I just learned that there is a `FormsAuthentication.Authenticate()`.

What is the purpose of `ValidateUser()` within `Membership`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In short, there are times when you might want to simply validate that a user is who they say they are without needing to persist an authentication cookie for any length of time.

Comment: So should I use the MembershipProvider.ValidateUser() within an override of FormsAuthentication.Authenticate() ?

Comment: @Coulton, the `Authenticate()` method will essentially do the same thing in this context, so it's not necessary to override.  Using the `ValidateUser()` method would in theory allow you to choose your provider, if you had more than one.  The `Authenticate()` method just uses the one configured in your web.config.

Comment: I've just noticed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.authenticate.aspx) that it says Authenticate() is obsolete and `The recommended alternative is to use the Membership APIs, such as Membership.ValidateUser. For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=252463.`.  So I should use Membership.ValidateUser() and do my forms authentication within that method

Answer (score 1):

It only check your data source (database) if the passed username and password exist in the database and match and returns true [Check MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.validateuser.aspx). If they don't match, it returns false

```
public static bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
```