# In MVC4, how do I do my own check on user login and password?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am currently using the built in login system that comes with MVC4 with Razor.  I would like to to do my own checking.  So I would have:

```
string userName, userPassword;
```

How do I do a checkup to make sure the user entered the correct name and password?

Is there something along the line of:

```
bool result = User.CheckLogin(userName, userPassword);
```

??

Comment: Yes there is. It is the built-in system. Why do you want to create your own?

Comment: I would like to do my own username/password check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See `Membership.ValidateUser` to test your own validation.  See this SO thread [What is the purpose of Membership.ValidateUser()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12095700/what-is-the-purpose-of-membership-validateuser)

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether user is logged in with this

```
if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
       // your code goes here  
    }
```

But if you want to make your custom logic you have to compare our username and password with related records in your User table in DB.

```
var context = new YourDbContextClass();
var yourUser = context.Users.FirstOrDefault(user=> user.Username==username && user.Password==password);
if(yourUser!=null)
{
   // user is logged in
}
```

Comment: But what if I want to do my own authentication with a string username and string password?